# "Prepared statements" for general variables?

Tags: php, variables

I guess that is some basic thing but to be honest I never had to do this before and now I am kind of stuck. Is it possible to define a string which also contains a variable but only define that variable AFTER the string was declared? Here is basic rundown example.

```
$string = 'What a ' . $var . ' day!';

$var = 'nice';

echo $string; // This should print "What a nice day!"
```

Notice how $var is defined only after $string is already declared, not before. I was thinking about some sort of variable variables, passing by reference, encapsulating into something or using OOP but so far no luck. Perhaps that is some basic syntax but that would be a first for me. This does not need to be strictly about variables. I guess this is similar to prepared statements in PDO. But I need to use such "prepared statements" in more general scope. Any hints?

**EDIT**

Stupid me, sorry. I forgot to mention the important thing (without it my situation is not so clear). The issue is the fact that the variable which I want to inject into a prepared string must come from general scope. So another example:

```
    function Test($var) {

    $string = What a ' . $var . ' day!';
    return $string;

}
$var = 'nice';
echo Test($var);
```

The above does not solve the case becouse I need to know about $var and call it manually when executing a function. In my case I want my prepared statement to seek for variables it was defined with only when I actually call for that prepared statement. If those variables exists in the current scope, use them. And throw an error only if they do not.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Im trying to write a function which will handle some old code and deal with some security holes. There are bunch of strings defined in general scope and they use a bunch of other string, also in general scope. I want to pack certain strings into a function and later just call for that function with parameter to extract this certain string ( ReturnString(5); for example). But those strings vary a lot. Some times it may be smth like 'One.$two.'three'; Sometimes it can be smth like "One.$two.$three.$four.'five';.

Comment: I guess I would need to pack all external strings into array and pass it to function which will process them and return the glued string. But I thought that there is an easier way, considering that vars like $two or $three (my prev. example) will be available in general scope anyway.

Answer (score 1):

define your `$var` first then add with string try

```
$var = 'nice';
$string = 'What a ' . $var . ' day!';
echo $string; // This should print "What a nice day!"
```

or if you want to keep $var after string try `str_replace()` like

```
$string = 'What a $var day!';
$var = 'nice';
echo str_replace('$var', $var, $string);
```

you are missing quote in `$string` and semicolon on function call try

```
function Test($var) {
    $string = 'What a ' . $var . ' day!';
    return $string;
}
$var = 'nice';
echo Test($var);
```

Answer (score 0):

A function stored in a variable maybe?

```
$dayis = function ($adj) {
  return 'What a ' . $adj . ' day!';
  }

$var = 'nice';

echo $dayis($var);
```

However this is quite rare and should probably not be needed. Please state better your problem, since this seems a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous function for that

```
$variable = 'bad';

$text = function() use($variable){
  return 'What a ' . $variable . ' day!';
}

echo $text();
```